# How to copy a csproj file using docker without visual studio and without docker compose?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

I just started a new solution with a .NET Core Project (2.1) using visual studio 15.8.8. It can run and debug it by setting the docker compose file as a startup project. It works!

Logically, I should be able to build the docker image with a simple commandline statement. However, it complains that the csproj cannot be found. This is strange. The file exist and as I told, I can run it from visual studio. I tried it from one directory up and the directory that has the dockerfile. Same problem.

How can I solve this? The only thing I want is simply build my image and then run it by just using docker commands.

[image: Screenshot of commandline]

[image: Commandline with directory itself]
Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TryNewDocker2/TryNewDocker2.csproj", "TryNewDocker2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TryNewDocker2/TryNewDocker2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TryNewDocker2"
RUN dotnet build "TryNewDocker2.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TryNewDocker2.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TryNewDocker2.dll"]
```

Het is the compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  trynewdocker2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}trynewdocker2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TryNewDocker2/Dockerfile
```

Logically, I want "docker-compose up" to keep working when fixing this problem.

Comment: Edit the question to include your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Just done in the post

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to do a `dotnet build` before doing `dotnet publish`, the build should be implied.

Comment: @Matthew You do have a point but this is the just the autogenerated dockerfile. First, I want to make that work (which should be easy because it is the default). Then I want to make that better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by the wrong root folder for the file path in dockerfile.

For launching from `Docker`, its root folder is `C:\Users\...\repos\TryNewDocker2`, but while running from `command`, its root fodler is `C:\Users\...\repos\TryNewDocker2\TryNewDocker2`, so the path for `TryNewDocker2.csproj` has changed from `TryNewDocker2/TryNewDocker2.csproj` to `TryNewDocker2.csproj`

Try dockerfile below:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 59162
EXPOSE 44342

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TryNewDocker2.csproj", "TryNewDocker2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TryNewDocker2/TryNewDocker2.csproj"
COPY . ./TryNewDocker2/
WORKDIR "/src/TryNewDocker2"
RUN dotnet build "TryNewDocker2.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TryNewDocker2.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TryNewDocker2.dll"]
```

**Update**

For working in both Docker and command, do not change your dockerfile, and from path below to run your command with specifying the dockerfile path.

```
C:\Users\...\repos\TryNewDocker2>docker build -t gogo -f TryNewDocker2/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but it introduces a new problem. The "docker-compose up" gives an error: "ERROR: Service 'trynewdocker2' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder986714315/TryNewDocker2.csproj: no such file or directory". It is a standard .NET Core project created with visual studio with a compose file in the solution folder and a docker file in the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who end up here years later like I did, I'll share my experience.

My problem was caused by the auto-generated Dockerfile that came from Visual Studio's "add > Docker Support..." was on the same level as my .csproj file.

The specific line causing me trouble was `COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]` which should have been just `COPY ["MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]`. Removing the extra `MyApp/` in front of the .csproj got the build working fine.

Special thanks to Edward in the answer above for pointing me in the right direction.