# I failed at :docker build -t my_aspnetcore .the brief error info is :invalid reference format

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, wechat

I want to create a docker image for my Asp.net Core application. The environment is CentOS7.5, and dotnet-sdk-2.1.500. Here is the full error message when I enter the command.

> docker build -t wechat .:
>   Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.547 MB
>   Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
>   Error parsing reference: "microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
>
> Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.547 MB
>   Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
>   Error parsing reference: "microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

I wonder is there any setup I did wrong? How can I get through it?

Comment: Could you please share your Dockerfile and the command you're using to create the docker image?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I think it's because of the version of docekr, After I tried to upgrade the docker 1.13 to docker-ce 18 suggested by the answer below,I solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `invalid reference format`, it is usually caused by the wrong docker version.

For `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base`, it uses the docker new feature named `multi-stage builds` which requires Docker 17.05 or higher.

Try to follow [Get Docker CE for CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/) to reinstall or upgrade your docker ce.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think your anwser solved my problem , but now when the build start , I stucked at step 7/17, the error message is :Step 7/17 : COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder544152321/WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj: no such file or directory . Do you know why ?

Comment: @FrankKane Do you build from `cmd` command or VS? This error seems to be related with your path which runs the command. Check [How to copy a csproj file using docker without visual studio and without docker compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049759/how-to-copy-a-csproj-file-using-docker-without-visual-studio-and-without-docker/53058152#53058152)

Comment: Yes , it is the path issue.Thanks again.